# Android libcorkscrew gives strange backtrace

Tags: android, android-ndk, signals

I am using libcorkscrew inside a sigaction to get a backtrace on Android (Yes, I am aware that libcorkscrew is not publically exposed).

I can get a backtrace from libcorkscrew but it gives me strange / incomplete result.

Did I forget something ?

Here is what I do :

```c
typedef struct map_info_t map_info_t;

typedef struct {
    uintptr_t absolute_pc;
    uintptr_t stack_top;
    size_t stack_size;
} backtrace_frame_t;

typedef struct {
    uintptr_t relative_pc;
    uintptr_t relative_symbol_addr;
    char* map_name;
    char* symbol_name;
    char* demangled_name;
} backtrace_symbol_t;

typedef ssize_t (*t_unwind_backtrace_signal_arch)(siginfo_t* si, void* sc, const map_info_t* lst, backtrace_frame_t* bt, size_t ignore_depth, size_t max_depth);
static t_unwind_backtrace_signal_arch unwind_backtrace_signal_arch;

typedef map_info_t* (*t_acquire_my_map_info_list)();
static t_acquire_my_map_info_list acquire_my_map_info_list;

typedef void (*t_release_my_map_info_list)(map_info_t* milist);
static t_release_my_map_info_list release_my_map_info_list;

typedef void (*t_get_backtrace_symbols)(const backtrace_frame_t* backtrace, size_t frames, backtrace_symbol_t* symbols);
static t_get_backtrace_symbols get_backtrace_symbols;

typedef void (*t_free_backtrace_symbols)(backtrace_symbol_t* symbols, size_t frames);
static t_free_backtrace_symbols free_backtrace_symbols;

void nativeCrashHandler_sigaction(int signal, struct siginfo *siginfo, void *sigcontext) {

    if (old_sa[signal].sa_handler)
        old_sa[signal].sa_handler(signal);

    if (unwind_backtrace_signal_arch != NULL)  {
        map_info_t *map_info = acquire_my_map_info_list();
        backtrace_frame_t frames[256] = {0,};
        backtrace_symbol_t symbols[256] = {0,};
        const ssize_t size = unwind_backtrace_signal_arch(siginfo, sigcontext, map_info, frames, 1, 255);
        get_backtrace_symbols(frames,  size, symbols);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "DUMP", "%s", (symbols[i].demangled_name ? symbols[i].demangled_name : symbols[i].symbol_name));
        free_backtrace_symbols(symbols, size);
        release_my_map_info_list(map_info);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a "strange" backtrace?  If you dereference a null pointer in the code that was executing when the signal hit, does the backtrace logged by debuggerd look different?  Incomplete traces are sometimes due to absent unwind directives in assembly sources.  Android has generally improved over time, but some versions would give you poor traces if you failed in certain functions.